# Consuming messages with RdKafka::KafkaConsumer c++:

Tags: c++, apache-kafka

I'm using librdkafka's c++ client and Confluent's dotnet client to consume messages.  The dotnet version consumes all of the records for a given topic and partition but the c++ client only consumes at most 10 records for the same topic and partition.  I've played around with the properties given here https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/CONFIGURATION.md so that both versions have the same configuration but nothing has worked yet.  Does anyone know why this would happen?

Comment: Are they in the same group (group.id)? If so; did you run the .NET client before the C++ client? This would make the sub-sequent C++ run pick up the committed offsets of the .NET client and only consume new messages. You can verify this by using a unique group.id on the C++ and set auto.offset.reset=earliest.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I changed the group.id  and set auto.offset.reset=earliest but I'm still getting the same subset of total records and msg->len() never returns anything bigger than 11331.

Comment: It would help if you provide your consumer configuration.

Comment: For the C# consumer I have             var config = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                { "group.id", "advanced-csharp-consumer" },
                { "enable.auto.commit", true },
                { "auto.commit.interval.ms", 5000 },
                { "bootstrap.servers", brokerList },
                { "fetch.message.max.bytes", 50 },
                { "default.topic.config", new Dictionary<string, object>()
                    {
                        { "auto.offset.reset", "smallest" }
                    }
                }
            };

Comment: For the C++ consumer I have the following              conf->set("auto.offset.reset", "earliest", errstr);
conf->set("default_topic_conf", tconf, errstr);

Comment: You are setting "auto.offset.reset" on the global "conf" object, which will instantiate an implicit default_topic_conf behind the scenes, but then you are overwriting that implicit tconf with your explicit tconf, reverting the "auto.offset.reset" back to its default value of "latest". Try setting "auto.offset.reset" on the tconf instead.

Comment: I've set "auto.offset.reset" to "earliest" for tconf instead of conf but there's still no change.  Other than changing this, the script is the same as the high level consumer example

Comment: So what does your full C++ consumer config look like now? And did you try changing to a unique group.id for each run?

Comment: Here's the config now:   tconf->set("auto.offset.reset", "smallest", errstr);
  conf->set("default_topic_conf", tconf, errstr);

Comment: That is not the full client configuration.

Comment: The other properties are back to their default setting

Comment: You are not configuring a group.id or bootstrap.servers, it is unlikely that the KafkaConsumer can work.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.  I did some more investigating.

Comment: The group.id is "unique", booststrap.server is "locallhost:9092" and topic is "timeAlignedData".  I ran the C# consumer with "group.id" set to "new_consumer" .  Each message that is returned contains all the expected records.  I'm also using the rdkafka_consumer_example with above configuration but "group.id" is set to "unique".  Each message that is returned contains only a subset of the  expected records.  The first message contained the first 10 records. The next returned 3 other records and the third returned the first 10 again.

Comment: I've ran the rdkafka_consumer_example on both MSVC 2015 and Linux(CentOS7) with the same results.  Also the topic only has one partition.

Comment: Okay, can you please provide the complete command line to run rdkafka_consumer_example?

Comment: ./LseConsumer -g group8 -b localhost:9092

Comment: That is not rdkafka_consumer_example.

Comment: Sorry that's the name of the application I created using the example.  The command is .\rdkafka_consumer_example_cpp.exe -g group8 -b localhost:9092 timeAlignedData

Comment: You are not specifying `-X topic.auto.offset.reset=earliest` so your consumer will start consuming from the end of the partition, and with no new messages coming in you not see any messages. Also make sure to use a unique group.id for each run.

Comment: I tried the following  ".\rdkafka_consumer_example_cpp.exe -b localhost:9092 -g group30 -X topic.auto.offset.reset=earliest timeAlignedData" but the results were the same.  I also tried the rdkafka_example and the results were also the same.

Comment: Figured it out.  The problem was in deserializing the message.  Thanks for your help and the library.

Comment: Great news. I posted an answer to help future people looking at this question.

Answer (score 0):

You are not specifying `-X topic.auto.offset.reset=earliest` (defaults to latest offset) so your consumer will start consuming from the end of the partition, and with no new messages coming in your consumer will not see any messages.
During testing also make sure to use a unique group.id for each run to avoid resuming from previously committed offsets.